# How to display groups returned by Get-NetFirewallRule in a useful format?

Tags: powershell

When running the below code to display firewall rules:

```
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule
$rules | Select Group
```

The group names are displayed e.g. `@FirewallAPI.dll,-30752`, `@FirewallAPI.dll,-34501`

Is it possible to display groups as in 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' UI? E.g. `'Core Networking'`, `'Network Discovery'`, `'File and Printer Sharing'`

Why are the groups displayed in this garbled format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a DisplayGroup property :

`$rules | % DisplayGroup`

Comment: `$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule`      
`$rules | Format-Table -Property DisplayGroup` the same results, just a little more understandable to someone new to PowerShell